# How to Connect Visual Studio Code with Azure GIT Repo

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-repos

I want to connect Visual Studio Code with Azure GIT Repo.

For this I have Azure GIT Repo with empty files, installed VS Code which have following details and installed Azure extension (Argutec Azure Repos)

[image]

When I type >Team: Signin I get following error

`(team) No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository`.

And also some time I get following error

`Command 'Team: Signin' resulted in an error (command 'team.Signin' not found)`

how I can git rid of above error.
the project I have on my local system which needs to be uploaded under Azure git repo

**EDIT**
Also I have given the path  under Tvc: Location

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To connect VS Code with Git repository from Azure Repos, you can try like as below:

1. If you want push you local code to a new Git repository on Azure Repos.

   - Create an empty Git repository on Azure Repos. This repository does not contain any code files.
     [image]
   - Open the folder of your local code on VS Code.
   - Go to '**Source Control**' tab on VS Code, if you local source code folder has not been initialized as a local Git repository, click '**Initialize Repository**'.
   - After the initialization, add the empty repository on Azure Repos as the remote of the local repository. You can navigate to '**...**' > '**Remote**' > '**Add Remote...**', enter the clone URL of the remote empty repository, and provide a remote name. When the first time to connect the remote, you may be asked to provide your login authentication such as you email and password.
   - Commit and push the code files from the local repository to the remote repository. After completing the push, you can open or refresh the web page of the remote repository, then you can see the code files haven been pushed to the remote.
     [image]
2. If you want to connect to an existing and not empty remote Git repository on Azure Repos.

   - Open VS Code to clone the remote repository to local.
   - Navigate to '**Source Control**' tab on VS Code, click '**Clone Repository**', enter the clone URL of the remote repository. After completing the clone, you can click the '**Open**' button to directly open the local repository on VS Code. When the first time to connect the remote, you may be asked to provide your login authentication such as you email and password.
     [image]
   - After you make some changes on the local repository, then commit and push these changes to the remote repository.
     [image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, its helps me a lot, well one problem is still here, when I do >Team: Signin , it gives me error
(team) No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.

Comment: Hi @SaadAwan, When you connect the local code to a new remote at the first time, after adding the remote, when pushing the local code to the remote, as I have shown in the GIF image of the scenario 1, you need to click **`...`** > **`Pull, Push`** > **`Push to...`** and select the remote you have added in the previous step. Don't directly click **`...`** > **`Push`**. Otherwise you may get the similar error that not found remote.